# Powershell script “on exit” event?

Tags: powershell

Instead of calling a function at the end of all scripts to perform cleanup tasks, I'm looking to register for an 'on return' event for when the script (not the PowerShell session) is finished.

- A script can return at various points though (eg, no records to process), so the current situation is problematic.
- `Register-EngineEvent` applies to the PowerShell session, and operators run scripts manually, thus it's problematic.

I can't find a list of built-in powershell events or an alternative solution.

Comment: Does "try-finally" block set suit you?

Comment: @Vesper if you write it as an answer I'll remove mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Vesper wrote it as a comment, but a `try`/`finally` block is definitely what I would suggest for this:

```psh
try {
    # some code
} finally {
    # this gets executed even if the code in the try block throws an exception
}
```